# How can I let my bot replies with a random reply when I command him?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

**I want when I command my bot, he replies with a random messages.**

**Is this correct??**

```
if(command === "memes") {

let replies = ["meme 1", "meme 2", "meme 3"];

let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

message.channel.send[random]
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem, are you getting any errors? is what you want to happen not happening? stack overflow isn't for code reviews or for people to tell you what you're doing is right.

Comment: He messed up setting up the command, that's all, and it probably returned `undefined` since he tried to call a non-existent variable `message.channel.send[random]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.channel.send()` is a function, not a variable you can use `[]` (array identifier) with. What you want to do is sent the string from the randomized number in the array. Try the following code:

```js
if(command === "memes") {

  // List Replies
  let replies = ["meme 1", "meme 2", "meme 3"];

  // Get a random number from `replies.length` instead so it'll be dynamic.
  // `replies.length` will return the length of the array, in this case `3`, so we can use it as such.
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length);

  // Send the message using `replies` number `random`
  message.channel.send(replies[random]);

}
```

If you still need help, try checking out these links:

- [Github Community - Community - Sending random messages](https://github.community/t/need-discord-bot-to-respond-with-random-messages-upon-command/116309)

Comment: Thank you so much @MinekoKayui it worked

Comment: No problem, it would be appreciated if you can mark this answer as correct :) Have a great day^^

Comment: sure have a great day you too :D